# Performing a dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu on a PC with 4 GB RAM?

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-10, boot-partition

Is it okay to do dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10 on my PC with 4 GB RAM or would there be less RAM available for either OS? I don't want my gaming performance on Windows to suffer.

Answer (score 2):

Your gaming performance in Windows won't suffer if you install Ubuntu alongside Windows. There is no decrease in performance in either OS in a dual boot because both Ubuntu and Windows operating systems in a dual boot use all the available RAM.

If you install an Ubuntu  guest OS in a virtual machine it will reduce performance in Windows only when the Ubuntu guest OS is running, because a virtual machine application installed in Windows only uses RAM when it is running.